# How can I downgrade Windows 7 Ultimate to Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, license

How can I downgrade from Windows 7 Ultimate to Home Premium without reinstalling Windows?  I want to use a Home Premium key and uninstall the Ultimate features.  How can I do this?

Comment: Is your Windows 7 Premium key a retail license (upgrade or full)?

Comment: It's an OEM license.

Comment: It is not going to work, unless you have never installed the OEM license. To quote [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/pages/licensing_faq.aspx): "After an OEM software license has been installed on a PC, the license may not be installed on or transferred to another PC."

Comment: No, this one has never been installed.  I just bought it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot downgrade editions.  You need to re-install the operating system using the correct edition,  then you can use that key.

You can go up in editions using anytime upgrade.

Edit:

Bonus Chatter:
The reasons are dependencies and money.  Allowing downgrades means developing a UI, and then endless testing and stomping bugs(this is IMP the biggest pain point).  I'd rather the company spend time on features I will use more than once.